# Finding all invariant measures for a (continiuous) Markov chain given by a Q-matrix

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $0<p<1$. I want to find **all** invariant measures $\pi$ for the asymmetric random walk on $Z$ given by the Q-matrix, that is defined as follows:

$q(x,x-1)=1-p, ~~q(x,x)=-1, ~~q(x,x+1)=p~~$ and zero elsewhere

For me a measure $\pi$ on $Z$ is invariant if

$\forall y\in Z, t>0: \pi(y)=\sum_{z\in Z}\pi(z) p_t(z,y)$,

where $p_t(z,y)$ is the probability that the Markov chain starting in $z$ takes the value $y$ at time $t$.

Except of the trivial one, that is $\pi\equiv c$ for $c\geq 0$ I can't find anything. But I'm quite sure that at least there exists no invariant distribution here.

Thanks in advance.